# How to change moment.js format that already formatted to DateTime

Tags: momentjs

I have a trouble with **`moment.js`**

In my case I have receive date time data format as `Moment(dateData).format('dddd LL')`

So, Output will look's like `Monday 15 December 2018`

But I want to convert that format to `(YYYY-MM-DD) or 2018-12-15`

**Is it possible to do this in moment js ?**

Comment: Which is the value of `dateData`? What did you tried so far? Are you looking for a pure JavaScript solution or you want to get `YYYY-MM-DD` using momentjs?

Comment: `dateData` is `2018-12-15`
I'm looking for `YYYY-MM-DD` by using moment.js

but I've already found the way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've already founded the way to solve this problem.

`var dateReceivedFromServer = 'Monday 15 December 2018'`

`Moment(dateReceivedFromServer, 'dddd LL').format('YYYY-MM-DD')`

and output is `2018-12-15`

Thanks